# Erro na paginação do Admin

Tags: wordpress, paginação

Olá, fiz uma migração do site *web.dominio.com.br* para *www.dominio.com.br*, não fiz mudança de pasta apenas de *url*. Alterei o *siteurl* e o *home* em `wp_options`, fiz um *replace* no `wp_posts`, `wp_options` e `wp_postmeta`, mudando as *urls*, o site e o menu funcionam corretamente, mas está aparecendo um erro na paginação no Admin.

Quando acesso todos os Posts e clico para *Ordenar por Data* ou para ir para a próxima página ele está chamando a *url* antiga, *http:// web.dominio.com.br/wp-admin/edit.php?orderby=date&order=desc*

Alguém já passou por isso ou tem ideia do que pode ser esse erro?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Os links que você está utilizando são gerados pela classe `WP_List_Table` e não têm nada a ver com o banco de dados. Apesar disso, antes de tentarmos qualquer conserto, é bom fazer uma limpeza do link no banco de dados e reiniciar os permalinks (só pra ter certeza):

1. Faz um dump do banco de dados, abre em um editor de texto e substitui todas as referências ao endereço antigo. Depois recarrega o banco de dados.
2. Altera a estrutura de permalinks pro padrão.
3. Nas configurações confere se o site_url e o home_url estão certos e salva de novo.
4. Volta a estrutura de permalinks pro que você usava.

Isso com certeza não resolveu o seu problema no wp-admin, mas pelo menos agora no BD e no .htaccess está tudo certo.

O seu problema está em uma variável do servidor. O `WP_List_Table` usa a variável `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` para pegar o endereço que você estava. Este erro normalemnte acontece com servidores que estão atrás de um proxy ou firewall mal configurado. Para resolver você pode:

1. Reconfigurar o servidor
2. Consertar pelo wp-config.php

Como nem sempre temos controle sobre a (má) configuração do servidor, vamos colocar um remendo no `wp-config.php`, antes da linha `require_once(ABSPATH . 'wp-settings.php');`

```
if ( ! empty( $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'] ) ) {
   $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] = $_SERVER['HTTP_X_FORWARDED_HOST'];
}
```

Isso deve resolver o problema. Se você encontrar mais algum erro, pode tentar uma solução mais completa, como [neste link](http://wolfgang.reutz.at/2009/06/12/using-wordpress-with-a-proxy-webserver-in-front/)

Comment: o ´$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']´ está apontando para o endereço correto.

Comment: estranho, porque os links que estão apontando para o site antigo utilizam exatamente essa variável... você tentou colocar no wp-config a alteração do hettp_host pro forwarded_host?

Answer (score 0):

Se não me engano, as páginas internas do WordPress não utilizam os options que vc alterou no banco. Isso funciona, juntamente com as rewrite rules,  para o front end do site. O back leva em conta a estrutura de pastas onde ele se encontra. Experimenta migrar os arquivos pra ver o que rola.

Comment: Caio não ouve mudança de pastas, apenas a mudança da URL do Site, já desativei e ativei os link's permanentes mas continua com o erro

Comment: você tentou mudar as pastas? acredito que esteja aí o problema

Comment: O site está na Raiz /var/www/html/  não mudei a pasta

A instalação do WP foi no web.dominio.com.br, para funcionar em paralelo com o site antigo que era em outro servidor.

Em seguida fiz mudança do web.dominio.com.br para www.dominio.com.br, os link's estão funcionando apenas a paginação no Admin que está chamando o web.dominio.com.br